# How to upload files in a UIWebView on an iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

Im developing an iPad app, and one of the components of my app has a UIWebView with a web page that has a browse button to upload a file (in this case, photos).

I am aware that apps cannot access the filesystem, but I have seen apps on the App Store that achieve this functionality with photos. Alot of these are written for the iPhone.

I don't want to use a third party app to get this functionality, I want to embed this functionality into my app.

I've already done a through search and can't find any development info on this.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate over here (this one was first though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889023/upload-a-photo-using-uiwebview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to upload files within a web view on iOS5 and earlier (this might be supported in iOS6, but I couldn't possibly comment on unreleased beta functionality ;-).

The apps you have seen that do this are almost certainly implementing the functionality using a native image picker control, not an HTML file upload field.

If you have seen the functionality working from within a web view, what they may have done is used the webview delegate to communicate back from the web view to the native code and triggered a native image picker. The image data can then be passed back to the web view as a base64 encoded data URL using JavaScript.