# Upload a photo using UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios

Suppose I have a web page (say filebrowse.html) in a remote server, having a browse file button, I want to access this page via a `UIWebView` and upload photo from my gallery. (The gallery is on the iPhone.)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, there is no way to "browse the filesystem" so you can't use a form in UIWebView to attach photos for upload. The answer is rather convoluted but here goes:

You're going to have to -

1. UIImagePickerController to get a picture from the photos album.
2. Determine the POST headers for the submit form
3. Encode the image as NSData
4. Write a POST request with NSURLConnection with the NSData object getting inserted in the proper header

I can't really give you the code for all of this because it needs to be broken down into all of those steps.

Comment: Thanks for answer , what ever steps you written I can do my only question is how to trigger event when user click on file browser button in ios side .

Comment: UIWebView's delegate object asks if it should load a URL, tells you when a URL is loading, and when that URL either completed or failed to load. If touching a button inside a webpage causes the webpage to load a new URL, you can use the delegate methods to find out the intention and intercept it there, and invoke a UIImagePickerViewController. UIWebView also has some crude javaScript functionality but there's really no way to monitor what goes on inside a UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - interesting. Have you tried accessing that page in native Safari? Will it let you browse on the phone? If not (and I'm assuming you're building an app here) you can just use a POST to the form in question (use curl and a browser web inspector to figure out parameters you need, etc).

Comment: yes I can able to access from safari and in my app also , have you any idea can you share with me .Thanks

Comment: If you are able to do it in Safari and actually upload a file, then a UIWebView will do it as well. Just tell the UIWebView (in code, perhaps) to load that URL specifically.

Comment: No in my app the file browser button is disable can I add a event when user click on that disabled button ?

Comment: Unfortunately, looking at a similar unanswered question here seems to indicate that you might be out of luck (as in, you'll have to do it yourself): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744761/how-to-upload-files-in-a-uiwebview-on-an-ipad

Answer (score 0):

may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915881/access-camera-from-uiwebview) will help, it shows you how to choose a photo from webview without using `<input type="file" />` in `<form></form>`