# Respond to AJAX call iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ajax, file-upload, uiwebview

I am trying to implement a photo upload system via a webview.

I have it working via the safari browser, but have yet to get it working via the webview. My research has led me to realise I need to use UIImagePickerController in order to capture the image file path, and have this method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info   {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation( [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] , 1.0);
    NSString *fullPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image_tmp.jpg"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:data attributes:nil] ) {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"file successfully written to path %@",fullPath],nil);
    }
}
```

However, I am having trouble working out how I intercept and respond to the ajax call via the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9889023/308315

Comment: Thanks, I didn't come across this post during my search. Will have a read through now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more experimenting I have arrived at a solution to my problem. It seems I was over engineering the problem so to speak.

My AJAX call needed to simply return the image path and the rest would be handled server side. All my research pointed to the fact that the UIImagePickerController was required in order to return the image path, however, this was actually not the case.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if(animated){
        NSLog(@"YES");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"NO");
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebview.com/photo-upload.php"];
        [photoview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }   
}
```

By using viewWillAppear and returning a Boolean for the animation, I was able to tell if the call was for the page load or the AJAX call. It was actually the page reloading that was preventing the upload, the file-path was being passed all along... Simple oversight by someone fairly new to iOS development, but perhaps this will help someone in a similar situation.

If anyone can elaborate on this or tidy up my code/explanation, please do!