# File uploading in iphone using vb.net

Tags: iphone, ios

The html tag for file uploading is not working in iphone:

`<input type="file" id="Fileid1" runat="server"/>`

It is showing inactive in iphone in aspx page. So how the file uploading can run in iphone using html...

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone File Upload with HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784352/iphone-file-upload-with-html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

File upload is **not supported** using a web interface in ios.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744761/how-to-upload-files-in-a-uiwebview-on-an-ipad).You can use some alternate mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked and it's working using below code:

input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">